# C++ std::fstream getline() stops reading file after first long line

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

I use std::fstream to read text files line by line with the member function getline(). It uses buffer of limited size, and sometimes lines on input are longer than the buffer. After the first reading of the long line `getline()` stopped read data, what was surprise for my after the debug of the code. The documentation states, that reading of the long line set the error flag **`failbit` , **it is described as usual situation, not runtime error or fatal failure (https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/). Documentation does not point any attention to this flag and does not describe, how to deal with long lines.

Do you know any documented way, how to precess long lines ? It should be, as this behaviour affect all class std::fstream, but I never see any descriptions or discussions.

The example of the program:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
 char buffer[10];
 std::string filename{"test.txt"};
 auto file=std::fstream(filename, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary );
 
 if(file.is_open()){
  size_t readBites{4};
   file.getline(buffer,readBites);
   auto length=std::strlen(buffer);
   auto lengthStream=file.gcount();
   std::cout << "Read "<<length<<"/"<<lengthStream<<":"<<buffer<<std::endl;
   file.getline(buffer,readBites);
   length=std::strlen(buffer);
   lengthStream=file.gcount(); 
   std::cout << "Read "<<length<<"/"<<lengthStream<<":"<<buffer<<std::endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

If test.txt file contains, for example:

```
1234567890
```

```
ABCDEFGHIJK
```

I expected output (like `fgets(...)` in C):

```
Read 3/3:123
```

```
Read 3/3:456
```

but it really is :

```
Read 3/3:123
```

```
Read 0/0:
```

I use limited size of buffer, as it is requirement of the client software, calling this code, it can be any size and processes long lines in short buffer.

Comment: You do know there is a [`getline` version for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) that allocates memory for the whole line, right?

Comment: Any attempt of reading the manual [std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)? *if `count - 1` characters have been extracted, then `setstate(failbit)` is called.*

Comment: _"... to read text files line by line"_ - Then why `std::ios_base::binary`?

Comment: @Homer512 I explain in the last sentence, that it is requirement is the client, calling convention, I must feel the provided buffer. Everything worked until long line was not tested on input. I reread the documentation and do not see any clear explanation, how to deal in this case, why I ignored it before.

Comment: @273K Yes, it is exacltly what I described in line 4 - flag is set. And what next? It is not described , how to exit in this situation in documented way. Than you for link, though it has the same description of getline, that in my link.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I use binary mode. Information about text file provided to explain, that I do not read binary file with predefined structure, files have lines of variable length with "\n" delimiter.

Comment: Why not click on `setstate()` on the manual page and getting known of `clear()`?

Answer (score 4):

As the documentation you linked to says:

> The [failbit](https://cplusplus.com/ios_base::failbit) flag is set if the function extracts no characters, **or if the *delimiting character* is not found once (n-1) characters have already been written to `s`**.

So, if you try to read more data than your buffer can hold, the stream's `failbit` state is set:

> Either the *delimiting character* was not found or no characters were extracted at all (because the *end-of-file* was before the first character or because the construction of `sentry` failed).

At that point, the stream won't read any more data:

> Internally, the function accesses the input sequence by first constructing a `sentry` object (with `noskipws` set to true). **Then (if [`good`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/)), it extracts characters from its associated stream buffer object** as if calling its member functions `sbumpc` or `sgetc`, and finally destroys the `sentry` object before returning.

Since the stream is no longer in a `good` state, it stops extracting characters. You have to [`clear()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) the stream to return it to a `good` state.

Comment: It would make sense. Could you point this documentation? I surfed C++ sites with documentation, but never find statement like this.

Comment: Does this mean, that every usage of fsteam's getline() must be followed by check of flag, comparing requested buffer length and received length, and clearing of the flag by clear() ?  It is not described anywhere. It is not bad procedure (it is like in C check every returned value of fgetc(...) != EOF ), but in was not mentioned at least where I looked.

Comment: Just use `if (file.getline(...`, the streams have the overloaded operator bool and operator!. Just click `istream` on the manual page.

Comment: @Vladlen yes, you always have to check the result before moving on. Also, cplusplus.com is not a very good reference site, use cppreference.com instead

Comment: I started to understand next actions, thanks to many comments. If error happened (except `failbit`), exception will be thrown in `readline()` and catched later in `catch()`. After `!file.readline()` I have to take care of `failbit`. If requested buffer size and actually read bytes equal (it is only one work case, other are errors), I call `clear()` and proceed with next I/O, otherwise it is other internal problem in `fstream`, and I throw exception to process it in corresponding `catch()`.